# Bootstrap.js not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

That is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html lang="ru">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
        <title>Tasks</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/mystyle/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/mystyle/equal-height-columns.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="css/mystyle/auto-colums.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="css/mystyle/navbar-style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        </head>
        <body>

        <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Tasks</a>
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#responsive-menu">
                        <span class="sr-only">Открыть навигацию</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>  
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="responsive-menu">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="index.php">Добавить задачу</a></li>
                        <li><a href="tasks.php">Список задач</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><b>Войти</b> <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul id="login-dp" class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li>
                                     <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                 <form class="form" role="form" method="post" action="login" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="login-nav">
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                             <label class="sr-only" for="inputLogin">Login</label>
                                                             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputLogin" placeholder="Логин" required>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                             <label class="sr-only" for="inputPass">Password</label>
                                                             <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPass" placeholder="Пароль" required>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="form-group btn-submit">
                                                             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Войти</button>
                                                        </div>
                                                 </form>
                                            </div>
                                     </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Bootstrap.js not working, cant undarstand why.

File directory:

```
-project
--index.php
--js
---bootstrap.js
```

This option I tried too:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I copied new project, in old the same project all works fine. 
I'm confused, thanks for any helps.

Comment: try to use it before `bootstrap.js` tether js `<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js' type='text/javascript'>`

Comment: @NiravJoshi not helped

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! There seems to be [a lot more code than what seems necessary for the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Could you see about trimming it down some, so we can better understand it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried looking in the console in your browser to see if it loads? Should be on your F12 dev tools on most browsers.
Also, try the CDN link: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Comment: using CDN css file solved my problem, but i still cant ynderstand why css file not working in project. I tried just copy my project and run copy, and css file not working..

Comment: Have you tried re-downloading the files? Not sure if you checked the console or not but it's a great habit to get into!

Comment: Yes, i re-download files, It did not help. Im new in html/css. When u said concolse, did u mean browser console? If yes, where i can see connected files in console. Btw, thx for ur time and help.